# Import XML into worksheet not workbook

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am trying to have Excel import 200 .xml files into separate worksheets.
I have some code that creates new worksheets, and that works. However I can't seem to find the proper code to import an .xml file into a worksheet rather then a workbook. I was hoping:

```
Workbooks.Worksheets.OpenXML
```

would work, but alas.

Is there a way to do this, or should I import them into a new workbook, copy that worksheet, close the newly created workbook without saving and so on?

For those interested: I found the quick and dirty method on this site as well: [How to fetch data from XML file to Excel sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620011/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-file-to-excel-sheet-using-vba-macro?rq=1)

Comment: "*should I import them into a new workbook, copy that worksheet*" Sure, why not? Have you tried?

Comment: Because that is a lot of processing that when not necessary can be avoided to speed up things.

Comment: And why build a dirty code when there is (possibly) a clean solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the dirty workaround. This works for me as for now my number of lookups remains low. However I still wonder if there is a neat way to do this.

[How to fetch data from XML file to Excel sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620011/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-file-to-excel-sheet-using-vba-macro?rq=1)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @KenWhite while that standard message is useful for external links, it isn't relevant for internal SO links.

Comment: If an SO link answers the question, then you should be voting to close the question as a duplicate instead of answering it. But you're right - there is a comment more specific to  the link being from SO. Just a minute and I'll add it here.

Comment: From the [help/closed-questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. There’s more information in our [help center article about duplicate questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](/help/privileges/close-questions) as such . If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
Sub test()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim objXMLFile As Object
   Dim list1 As Variant
   Dim data1 As String
   Dim i As Integer
   
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
   ws.Range("A:A").Clear
   Set objXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
   objXMLFile.Load ("C:\example.xml")

   Set list1 = objXMLFile.SelectNodes("/sample/items/item/text()")
   
   For i = 0 To (list1.Length - 1)
      data1 = list1(i).NodeValue
      ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = data1
   Next i
End Sub
```