# Is it possible to parse XML with using Excel(VBA)?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, soap

I have a xml file, I can run it by using Soap UI. In Soap, I open a new worksheet, paste my xml code, and click the run button, and it makes what I want.

I want to the same thing with using Excel(VBA).

Scenario:

1. I paste the xml content to A1 cell.
2. Create a button and write the code which I need
3. Click the button and parse the xml content

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620011/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-file-to-excel-sheet-using-vba or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423644/load-xml-into-excel-through-vba

Comment: No, it is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Only for paragraph 2 you can use the build tool of excel for import xml file into the excel-

Click on tab "data"->"from other sources"->"from xml data inport"