# Application.sendkeys() does not work when concerned tab (in ribbon) is not visible

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have XML mappings & a macro-button in my excel sheet (which fires this macro command) -

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Application.SendKeys ("%lt") '%lt (alt + L + T) - shortcut to import xml option in Developer tab
'above code opens import xml in Developer tab, enabling the user to import the XML file to map data.
End Sub
```

When I sent the sheet to my partners, they said the button doesn't work; Later I found out that in my computer's Excel the Developer tab (in ribbon) is visible, and in theirs it's not visible. I temporarily fixed the problem for my partners' computers (I enabled the Dev. tab & then it worked), but obviously I cannot fix for all my users, nor can I ask them to enable the developer tab on their excel. *as most of them probably don't know how to enable it...*

What should I do in order to invoke the Import XML action through macro (highlighted below), irrespective of whether the user has the Developer tab enabled or not? Kindly guide... Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [A guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620011/how-to-fetch-data-from-xml-file-to-excel-sheet-using-vba).

Comment: Hi @BigBen - Thanks for referring the post; But I tried both answers, they overwrite the XML Mappings I've set in my sheet. What I want to do is just somehow trigger the Import XML button through macro. Kindly guide... :)

Comment: `CommandBars.ExecuteMso ImportXmlFile` is supposed to be like clicking that button. I wonder if that would work.